# Python interpreting JSON values to input & extract the output required

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import json
import requests
def funcname():
response1 = requests.get('https:aig.com/e/id')
resp = json.loads(response1.text)
print(resp)
print(type(resp)
```

If I run the above the program, I am getting output like below from json URL which I parsed:

```py
{'values': [{'id': '123456','name': 'person1'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person2'},{'id': '566','name': 'person3'}, {'id': '-1123678','person4': 'four'},{'id': '-1123678','name': 'person5'}]> <class 'dict'>
```

There are actually 100+ id's & name, I just gave 5 above

Suppose if I ask for 'name' of that person and user gave input as 'person3', output should return with ID 566

I would like to create a python program to ask for input for person name and print the id based on person name we give.

Comment: The code you've shown is syntactically incorrect. Also, that URL does not respond with any useful content as it will return HTTP 404. However, once you have valid JSON in the variable resp and if it's in the format you've suggested, then just iterate over the list of dictionaries given by resp['values'] and evaluate the 'name' key. If it matches, emit the 'id' key's value

Comment: I would reshape the data, creating a new dictionary with the key of name and a value of the id.